# I've made a little survey in html, but i want the submit button to send the information to a different page. can someone give me some advice please?

Tags: html

I made a survey, and want the information sent to another page in html  after clicking the submit button. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have tried some other code others have made, but it sends me to the page also, and doesn1t show the information.
(edit: I've realized i haven't given enough information to get what i need, so let me just update you guys. i'm making a website for my families shirt company. we make and design custom shirts and sell it to people. i've already made a survey, but don't know how to transfer the data to a different page, so if someone can help that would be great. thank you!)

```
     <br>
     <h3>Size</h3>
     <form>
     <select>
     <option value="XS">Extra Small</option>
     <option value="S">Small</option>
     <option value="M">Medium</option>
     <option value="L">Large</option>
     <option value="XL">Extra Large</option>
     <option value="XXL">Double Extra Large</option>
     </select>
     </form>
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3>Quantity</h3>
     <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100">
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3>Colour</h3>
     <form>
     <select>
     <option value="Red">Red</option>
     <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
     <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
     <option value="Green">Green</option>
     <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
     </select>
     </form>
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3>Design</h3>
     <form>
     <label>Description of Design:</label>
     <input type = "text"
     id = "myText"
     value = "Design Here">
     </form>
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3>Email for further contact</h3>
     <form>
     <label>Email:</label>
     <input type = "text"
     id = "myText"
     value = "someone@example.com">
     <br>
     <br>
     <form action="OrdersAndDonationsPage.html" > 
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
     </form> 
     </center>
```

So far I haven't gotten anything to work, and would like some advice to send information from a survey to a different page.

Comment: Do not put HTML forms inside other HTML forms, that doesn't work. Also, you only need one HTML form with the correct `action="..."` attribute you want to send the values to.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the "action" attribute on your form tells the browser where to send the data.

Also, it will send data that is inside your form. The snippet you posted doesn't show anything inside the form except the submit button itself.

If you want the destination page to display the sent data, it needs to be a dynamic page - simple HTML won't do it.

Is there a server-side language you are prepared to use? PHP, Python, .NET, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @thelr said you need a dynamic page to achieve that, I added some code to exemplify it.

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Survey</h2>

<form action="/page2.html">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        retrieveData = function() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const firstName = urlParams.get('firstname');
            const lastName = urlParams.get('lastname');
            const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
            resultDiv.innerHTML = `Name: ${firstName} - ${lastName}`

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="retrieveData()">
   <div id="result">
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```